# MySql Insert signal if where clause fails

Tags: mysql, error-handling, raiserror

As part of a chained sequence of transactional queries, I'm inserting values that exist in a temporary table into a new table.

Every query is validated for errors in PHP using:

```
if (!mysqli_query($dbc, ....) {$errors[] = mysqli_error($dbc);}
```

If an error occurs it gets pushed into the errors array and the entire sequence is not commited.

With this approach I'm having trouble validatiesg queries that **DO NOT CAUSE AN ERROR** but **DO NOT MEET WHERE CLAUSE CONDITIONS**

Is there a way to get MySQL to throw an error signal when the **WHERE CLAUSE** conditions are not met?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to find how many rows are inserted from the last query and generate your own error in case no rows are inserted.

Comment: I was thinking of using that as a backup plan

Comment: there is another way that i know which uses the same technique but, it's done in a stored procedure. If this option is not good enough I can write that for you.

Comment: Or `mysqli_num_rows` for `SELECTs`.